# Why should I use references to a base class, I can't understand the difference

Tags: c#

Can someone explain what is the main difference between those two part of code, and why or when I should use a reference to a base class, as for me it is the same thing.

```
internal class MyBaseClass
{
    public string Field = "Hello";
    public void Print()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("This is the base class.");
    }
}

internal class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public string FieldDerived = "Coucou";
    public new void Print()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("This is the derived class.");
    }
    public new void Print2()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("This is the derived class.");
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        MyDerivedClass derived = new MyDerivedClass();
        MyBaseClass mybc = (MyBaseClass) derived;
                            // ↑
                            //   Cast to  base clas
    }
}
```

And this is the code, that for me do the exactly same thing :

```
internal class MyBaseClass
{
    public string Field = "Hello";
    public void Print()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("This is the base class.");
    }
}

internal class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public string FieldDerived = "Coucou";
    public new void Print()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("This is the derived class.");
    }
    public new void Print2()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("This is the derived class.");
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        MyDerivedClass derived = new MyDerivedClass();
        MyBaseClass mybc = new MyBaseClass();
                               // ↑
                               //   Use the base class 
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the same thing as what?

Comment: I can access the exactly same methods / fields, with derived and mybc, I can't really understand what is the point of a reference.

Comment: looks like the bottom call- `MyBaseClass mybc = new MyBaseClass();

vs. (MyBaseClass) derived;`

Comment: In the first example, they're the same instance. In the second example, they're two different instances.

Comment: Both codes are **NOT** the same. In the above code, you are clearly assigning `derived` to `mybc`, whereas in the below code, you are clearly creating and saving a **new instance** of a `MyBaseClass`.

Comment: Also note that you are doing member hiding, not inheritance in this instance. So even though you are inheriting, you aren't strictly `override`ing the base methods. Referencing the base type that is having its members hidden is a way to bypass the hiding. However, with proper use of `override` it is not possible to bypass the derived implementation if the underlying object is actually a derived type.

Comment: Your two simple examples are functionally equivalent, in fact you needen't have a base and derived class because you don't actually use either.

Comment: First example uses a single instance (whatever you do to `mybc` will affect `derived`). Second example uses two separate instances.

Comment: Wow thank you very much for these answers it is now clear.

Comment: You should avoid the use of the `new` keyword for shadowing and prefer `override` where possile. When using `new` you should appreciate the consequences. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two differences between the usages.

In the first example, the cast is unnecessary, and mybc and derived both point to the same object, which is an instance of the derived class. You can always treat derived classes as if they are instances of the base class (because they are), no casting needed.

In the second example, they are entirely separate object instances and the referenced objects are actually separate types as well.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that you create only one object in the first example and two objects in the second.

1. Create object and cast to an object of its base class. Stripping off all the functionality added by MyDerivedClass. All changes done before casting will remain.
2. Create an object of MyDerivedClass and on object of MyBaseClass which have nothing to do with each other.

```
 public void TestThisStuff()
        {
            // 1 example
            MyDerivedClass derivedObj = new MyDerivedClass();
            derivedObj.Field = "Changed field";
            derivedObj.FieldDerived = "Changed derived field";
            MyBaseClass baseObj = (MyBaseClass)derivedObj;
            // baseObj.Field value will be "Changed field"
            // baseObj.FieldDerived will not be accessible because it is not presend in the base class
```

// 2 example
            MyDerivedClass derivedObj2 = new MyDerivedClass();
            derivedObj2.Field = "Changed field";
            derivedObj2.FieldDerived = "Changed derived field";
            MyBaseClass baseObj2 = new MyBaseClass();
            // baseObj2.Field value will be "Hello"
            // baseObj2.FieldDerived will not be accessible because it is not presend in the base class
            baseObj2.Field = "Change my field because it's not related to anything else."
            // derivedObj2.Field value will be "Changed field"
            // derivedObj2.FieldDerived will not be accessible because it is not presend in the base class
        }

Answer (score 2):

Derived classes are for implementing an is-a relationship.  Imagine a class:

```
internal class MySpottedDogClass : MyDogClass : MyAnimalClass
```

Because a Spotted dog is a dog, and a dog is an animal

If I create a new spotted dog

```
MySpottedDogClass rover = new MySpottedDogClass();
```

Then I can call

```
rover.countSpots()
```

An action that applies only to spotted dogs.  Method is part of SpottedDog class

```
rover.bark()
```

This applies to all dogs, so it is implemented in the dog class

```
rover.weight()
```

This applies to all animals, so it is implemented in the animal class.  A subclass is a way of creating a more detailed version of something general.  I think you need to read up a little on object-oriented design

Maybe it helps to think of your design in these terms.

Your first example is like

```
SpottedDogClass rover = new SpottedDogClass();
DogClass dogReferenceToRover = (DogClass) rover;
```

They both refer to the same object.  dogReferenceToRover.bark() is ok.  dogReferenceToRover.countSpots() is not valid because you can not do that to a dog (only a spotted dog) and the reference has the type, not the object.

Your second example is like this

```
SpottedDogClass rover = new SpottedDogClass();
DogClass fido = new DogClass();
```

This time you have made a spotted dog and a dog.  There are 2 objects.

Answer (score 1):

The cast in the first example is redundant, because it's always legal to treat a derived class as if it were the base class.

If you want to override the Print method (which is probably what you want in this scenario) mark it as `virtual` in the base class, and as `override` in the derived class. Then you will get different behavior between the base class and derived class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do in 'Use the base class'.

Normally, if you have a reference to a derived class you do not need to cast it to its base class.  Normally, you use a base class and derived classes when you are 'using' abstractions of the derived classes.  Maybe you know this, so I don't mean any disrespect.  For example, your base class could be Animal and your derived classes are Dog and Cat.  The abstraction in the base class could be Eat.  So if you have a list of Animals, you can feed them all by calling the abstract method Eat without knowing what kind of animal each one is and without having to cast each animal to its derived class.

Sorry if is not what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider a contrived example,

```
abstract class Cake
{
    public virtual bool Edible { get { return true; } }
}

class PooCake : Cake
{
    public new bool Edible { get { return false; } }
}

class TurdCake : Cake
{
    public override bool Edible { get { return false; } }
}
```

and the the following snippet

```
var turd = new TurdCake();
var poo = new PooCake();
Console.WriteLine(
    "PooCake is{0} edible",
    poo.Edible ? string.Empty : " not");
Console.WriteLine(
    "PooCake is{0} edible",
    (Cake)poo.Edible ? string.Empty : " not");
Console.WriteLine(
    "TurdCake is{0} edible",
    turd.Edible ? string.Empty : " not");
Console.WriteLine(
    "TurdCake is{0} edible",
    (Cake)turd.Edible ? string.Empty : " not");
Console.ReadKey();
```

You'll realise that you should use the `new` keyword very carefully because it breaks the inheritence model. In this instance it could leave you eating base poo cake.

If you debug and step through the code you'll see that, in the case of `TurdCake` the property is correctly overridden and the base implementation is inaccesible. In the `PooCake` example the property is only shadowed, a reference to the base type exposes the base implementation. This could lead to unsatisfactory results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your question needed to be about polymorphic behavior of classes in c#?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a derived class will hide a method or property defined in the base class, for many varied reasons.

Consider this example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string GetSomeValue() { return "base class"; }
}
```

In a derived class, this could be "rewired" by a new method:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // hides the base method (basically you're hijacking the signature)
    public new string GetSomeValue() { return "derived class"; }
}
```

Note that you can pretty much `new` any signature on the base class. It's a pretty powerful way to hijack the signatures, and should be used with caution.

Polymorphically, an instance of `DerivedClass` will always return `"derived class"` when `GetSomeValue` is called.

Sometimes, though, it might be very crucial to call the base class method, instead of the derived class method.  In which case it would make sense to upcast the derived instance like this:

```
var result = ((BaseClass)derivedInstance).GetSomeValue();  // returns "base class"
```

When you upcast (`(BaseClass)derivedInstance`), you are able to make the derived class ignore it's own `new` method and invoke the base class method instead. This could make sense in certain situations, but unless you're doing some component design or other polymorphically heavy code-lifting, I don't think you will see this on a day-to-day basis. Well, at least, *I* haven't (shields eyes).